# Drupal entityQuery multiple node types and join

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Looking to join multiple nodes via a query and join. Let's say one node has a matching ID of another field in another node. I would like to join them into an array so that I can output other fields with them indexed together on the same ID.  Example: node1.nid and node2.field.target_id

How do I do this?

```
$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->accessCheck(FALSE)
->join('node2', 'n2', 'n.nid = n2.field.target_id');
->condition('type', 'node1', 'node2')
->sort('title')->execute();

$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);

$response = array();
```

Comment: Is there any condition that determines "another node" first? Or do you want to get all the `node1` - `node2` pairs that satisfy `node1.id = node2.field.target_id`?

Comment: I have two nodes, each node has many fields, the only thing they can be joined by is an ID that matches. I need to join the two nodes at that ID (each will be its own array), and then pull other fields from those nodes, like title or date.  The response can be all data, I will be exporting certain fields/arrays as JSON after nodes are joined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely doable and it looks like you're almost there, but it looks like you're combining the Database API with the Entity API, specifically trying to run Database joins on EntityQuery fetches.

Now, if you want to continue the Database query route, which may make it a little easier to join the values of multiple entities and output them, this is what I would recommend:

The first thing that I notice is that you're attempting to chain the join.  Unfortunately, according to the [Database API Docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/joins)

> Joins cannot be chained, so they have to be called separately (see Chaining).

I have done similar to this with a join between two custom content types.  Here is the code I used:

```php
   $connection = Database::getConnection();
   if ($connection->schema()->tableExists('companies') && $connection->schema()->tableExists('users')) {
      $query = $connection->select('companies', 'c');
      $query->join('users', 'u', 'c.sourceid1 = u.sourceid1');
      $results = $query->fields('u', ['destid1', 'sourceid1'])
        ->fields('c', ['destid1'])
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

      return $results;
    }
```

Now this assumes that you've brought in `Drupal\Core\Database\Database`, but let's walk through the process.

`$connection = Database::getConnection();`

This is fetching the database connection for your site

`if ($connection->schema()->tableExists('companies') && $connection->schema()->tableExists('users')) {`

This is a check I always do to make sure the tables I'm working with exist.

`$query = $connection->select('companies', 'c');`

One of your tables needs to be the "base" table.  In this case, I chose `companies`.

`$query->join('users', 'u', 'c.sourceid1 = u.sourceid1');`

This line is where the join actually happens.  Notice that it's not chained, but it's own command.  We're joining these tables, users and companies, on this sourceid1.

```php
      $results = $query->fields('u', ['destid1', 'sourceid1'])
        ->fields('c', ['destid1'])
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
```

This is where I'm pulling whichever fields I want from both entities. In this case I want `destid1` and `sourceid1` from my user table and `destid1` from my company table.

The `->execute()` call actually runs the query, and `->fetchAll()` returns an array of all matching results. This will get you to being able to JSONify all the things.

However, if you want to stick with the entityQuery route, that's also viable.  My personal preference is to use a regular query for more complex things and an entityQuery if I just need to get a value from a single field or return a single entity.

For an entityQuery, well, that's a bit different.  I wouldn't really recommend using an entityQuery for a join here.  Instead, using `entityTypeManager` if you know or can get the matching value from both tables.

For example, let's assume that `field_content_type_a_id` on content type A matches `field_related_type_a_id` on content type B.

You could load one, let's go with type A for now:

```php
// Get the current NID somehow... that's up to you
$entity_a = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->load($nid);
// Get the value of the field you want to match to the other content type
$matching_value = $entity_a->get('field_content_type_a_id')->getValue();
// Get the entities with matching type A values
$entity_b_array = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')
  ->loadByProperties(['field_related_type_a_id' => $matching_value]);

// Do something with $entity_b_array.
```

Comment: This is great and helps me understand a lot with understanding @JDDoesDev!  How would I go about doing the first method if all content is in the node table?  Using your example, let's say the users and companies are types in the node table and aren't actually separate tables?  Let's say companies.nid and users.field_programs.target_id match.  Many thanks!

Comment: @user3460707 Then you might need to join the node table to itself, or to one of the related field tables, such as `node_field_data` or `node__field_my_field`. Try opening the Drupal database in HeidiSQL or something else, and view the tables and values, so you can see and understand how all the data is structured. See also [Database schema | Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1785994)